# Playing Live streamed audio through Java

Tags: java, audio, cross-platform, streaming

Are there any java libraries out there that can handle live streamed audio such as an internet radio stream that can then be played back using Java?
I've looked into stuff like Xuggler/FFMpeg but I'm not sure if they can handle the fact that I'm just trying to play a live stream.
It would have to be able to handle most/all of the formats that internet radio stations usually stream in.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at JMF - Java Media Framework

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html

On the Wikipedia site is also a list of alternatives:

1. Freedom for Media in Java (FMJ) An API-compatible with JMF alternative !
2. JavaSound
3. QuickTime for Java
4. IBM Toolkit for MPEG-4
5. Jffmpeg
6. jvlc
7. vlcj
8. gstreamer-java
9. Cortado, a complete player for Ogg Vorbis and Theora in a Java applet
10. Directshow <> Java Wrapper
11. Fobs4JMF
12. JLayer MP3 library
13. Xuggler
14. Video4Linux4Java